# How to query for posts (hierarchical custom post type) that have children but are NOT top level?

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, pre-get-posts, hierarchical

I'm trying to create a custom filter for a custom post type that will display only posts that have children – `post_parent__not_in => 0` won't work because these posts have parents. I'm trying to target posts "in the middle", not top level posts.

This has to be just simple query (no checking in the loop) as it will be used with the `pre_get_posts` hook.

Comment: It’s not possible. At least not with WP_Query. Posts don’t have any information about their children attached to it. That relationship only exists as the parent property of child posts. You might be able to achieve this by modifying the SQL directly with the posts_join and posts_where filters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use filters to modify the SQL. I added something unique in the post_type so I could filter only this query and not change anything else.

The query for example

```
$query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'something_unique_for_filter'));
```

And the filter

```
function custom_where($where, $query) {
    global $wpdb;
    if(false !== strpos($where, 'something_unique_for_filter')) {
        $where = " AND post_type='page' AND post_parent != 0 AND ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT post_parent FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type='page')";
    }
    return $where;
}
add_filter('posts_where', 'custom_where', 10, 2);
```

To add support for meta query first step is to add `meta_key` to the `WP_Query` so it INNER JOIN the postmeta table.

```
$query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'something_unique_for_filter', 'meta_key'=>'something'));
```

And the filter with meta

```
function custom_where($where, $query) {
    global $wpdb;
    if(false !== strpos($where, 'something_unique_for_filter')) {
        $where = " AND ( $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'test' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = '123' )
        AND post_type='page' AND post_parent != 0
        AND ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT post_parent FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type='page')";
    }
    return $where;
}
add_filter('posts_where', 'custom_where', 10, 2);
```

Comment: This lead me into the right direction, thanks! I learned about `posts_where` and were able to apply it to my custom filter dropdown. Could you help me add a post meta query to the SQL? I'm looking for posts that also have a specific value in a custom field.

Comment: @Jusi Check the answer I added example for meta query.